# How to speed up MySQL query that is a carthesian

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose having a table named `contact` with next structure:

```
id INT -- primary key,autoincrement,index 
firstname VARCHAR (255),
lastname VARCHAR(255),
type ENUM
```

Executing such query:

```
SELECT c1.id AS c1_id, c2.id AS c2_id
FROM contact c1
INNER JOIN contact c2 ON c1.firstname = c2.firstname AND c1.lastname = c2.lastname
WHERE c1.id <> c2.id AND c1.type=c2.type
```

is ok on a small ammount of records... but when the record count grows from 30-40 to 1000 this query is very slow.Need to abstract from the record count and speed up this query maximum as possible.Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you joining the same table?

Comment: What indexes do you have on firstname/lastname and/or type? What is the result of an EXPLAIN on the query?

Comment: 1000? 1000 is nothing. OK. 1. That index is redundant. 2. Create an index instead on (firstname, lastname, type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id), firstname, lastname
FROM contact
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)>1
```

this will return all duplicated names. If you want the IDs you could then use a JOIN:

```
SELECT
  contact.id
FROM
  contact INNER JOIN (SELECT firstname, lastname
                      FROM contact
                      GROUP BY firstname, lastname
                      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)>1) dup
  ON contact.firstname=dup.firstname AND contact.lastname=dup.lastname
```

Comment: Damn you. Thats what i was typing :)  +1

Comment: Great example but i need to select the pairs of id's, so the problem occurs when they begin to repeat... for ex  1 - 2 is same as 2-1.

Comment: @VitKos but what if there are more ids duplicated, and not just two? what do you want to return? I was thinking about adding GROUP_CONCAT(id) on my the first query

Comment: Yeah sure.. there can be a lot of duplicates... so i want to fetch only one pair from similar.. for ex: if the result contains 1-2 and 2-1 I want to exclude 2-1 pair... and same story for other duplicates

Comment: @VitKos to include 1-2 and exclude 2-1 you should use `c1.id < c2.id` instead of `c1.id <> c2.id` in your original query... but I think that using group_concat should return what you need

Comment: Group_concat doesn't do what I need, but your answer helped me to reduce the amout of records twice, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Small deviation from fthiella's answer (just incase this is what you need):

```
SELECT group_concat(id) as ids, firstname, lastname
FROM contact
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
```

The query above will fill column ids with a comma seperated list of id's for each firstname+lastname combo.

Comment: close but not quite.. read my last comment to @fthiella 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Except for the "<>", your query's fine (In fact, it may even be fractionally faster than the alternatives put forward!). It's just your indexes that need some work...

```
 CREATE TABLE contact
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 ,lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 ,type ENUM('small','medium','large') NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO contact VALUES
 (NULL,'John','Brown','small'),
 (NULL,'Bill','Red','small'),
 (NULL,'Paul','Orange','medium'),
 (NULL,'Mike','Green','large'),
 (NULL,'John','Scarlet','small'),
 (NULL,'John','Cyan','medium'),
 (NULL,'Fiona','Brown','large'),
 (NULL,'John','Brown','small'),
 (NULL,'Chris','Copper','medium'),
 (NULL,'Steve','Silver','large');

 INSERT INTO contact SELECT NULL,x.firstname, y.lastname, z.type FROM contact x, contact y, contact z;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     1010 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec) 

 SELECT c1.id c1_id
      , c2.id c2_id
   FROM contact c1
   JOIN contact c2 
     ON c1.firstname = c2.firstname 
    AND c1.lastname = c2.lastname
    AND c1.type=c2.type
  WHERE c1.id < c2.id; 

  ...
  ...
  |  1006 |  1008 |
  +-------+-------+
  5634 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

So, now let's add an index on (firstname,lastname,type)...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;

 CREATE TABLE contact
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 ,lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 ,type ENUM('small','medium','large') NOT NULL
 ,INDEX(firstname,lastname,type)
 );

 INSERT INTO contact VALUES
 (NULL,'John','Brown','small'),
 (NULL,'Bill','Red','small'),
 (NULL,'Paul','Orange','medium'),
 (NULL,'Mike','Green','large'),
 (NULL,'John','Scarlet','small'),
 (NULL,'John','Cyan','medium'),
 (NULL,'Fiona','Brown','large'),
 (NULL,'John','Brown','small'),
 (NULL,'Chris','Copper','medium'),
 (NULL,'Steve','Silver','large');

 INSERT INTO contact SELECT NULL,x.firstname, y.lastname, z.type FROM contact x, contact y, contact z;

 SELECT c1.id c1_id
      , c2.id c2_id
   FROM contact c1
   JOIN contact c2 
     ON c1.firstname = c2.firstname 
    AND c1.lastname = c2.lastname
    AND c1.type = c2.type
    AND c1.id < c2.id; 

  |   775 |   776 |
  ...
  |  1006 |  1008 |
  +-------+-------+
  5634 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: any suggestions on indexes ? except to make an index on (firstname, lastname, type )

Comment: That's all you need to do. The query will be 30x faster!